# Кривичи: происхождение названия

Tags: этимология

Было такое славянское племя — кривичи (не знаю, есть сейчас их потомки). Интересно было бы знать, почему они так назывались? Слово какое-то не благозвучное, будто бы от — *кривого*, что для самоназвания как-то странно. Может быть, кто-то знает, почему именно *кривичи*?

Answer (score 2):

В словаре Фасмера есть такая статья:

Кривичи
(мн.) – вост.-слав. племя по верхнему течению Зап. Двины, Днепра и Волги (Пов. врем. лет; см. Барсов, Очерки 174 и сл.), ср.-греч. Κριβιτζοί, Κριβιτσηνοί (Конст. Багр., Adm. Imp. 9). **Получили название по имени родоначальника племени *Кривъ (см. криво́й**); см. Первольф, AfslPh 7, 594. Отсюда по народн. этимологии – криви́ч "неискренний, фальшивый человек", моск., владим., тульск. (см. Труды Сарат. арх. ком. 24, 7 и сл.), под влиянием выражения криви́ть душо́й. Из русск. заимств. лтш. krìevs "русский", Krìevija "Россия" (см. М.–Э. 2, 284), krìevisks "русский", лит. kriẽvai мн.; см. также Буга, ZfslPh 1, 26; ИОРЯС 17, 1, 16. Совершенно нелепо сближение с др.-исл. Hreiðgotum (Видеман, ВВ 28, 52 и сл.), которое связано скорее с англос. Hrǽdas "готы", др.-исл. hreiðr "гнездо", согласно Хольтхаузену (Awn. Wb. 126). Этимологический словарь русского языка. — М.: Прогресс М. Р. Фасмер 1964—1973